# Integration with Arabic text from MS SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, integration, arabic-support

I have a project which requires integration between 2 databases. One is hosted in server1 and using MSSQL Server, and one is hosted in Server2 and using MySQL.

I need to update the table of Customer in MySQL database on frequent basis (twice per day) from the “Customers” table in the MSSQL Server; noting that the table in MSSQL Server includes Arabic text.

How does I achieve this?

Comment: For the MySQL side, [UTF-8 All the Way Through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through), presuming you're using UTF-8 and not some other character set like [Windows-1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256).

Comment: try mysql workbench and make  a database migration  script, when it works save it and run it when needed

Comment: @tadman SQL Server only added support for UTF-8 very recently (but older versions do support Unicode using UTF-16 with `nvarchar`).